# Start a process in Windows efficiency mode

Tags: windows

I noticed that the Windows 11 task manager has an option to switch a process to "Efficiency Mode".  When doing this, it looks like the process is pushed over to E-cores on my Intel CPU.

Is there some way to start a process in "Efficiency Mode".  As a simple example lets say I want to run `calc` in efficiency mode from the command line. How would I go about this without setting it in the task manager?

Using The following PowerShell script, I can see processes running that start with "abc". Process name is abc123.exe

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |
Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith("abc") } |
Select-Object ProcessID, Name, Path, Priority  |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I tried changing the efficiency mode on and off in the task manager but the priority remains the same so that's not it. My guess is that this is a brand new parameter in win11.